# How to redirect from my App to "Addison Lee ride App" for redirect by deep link in iPhone application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am using the code below for open Addison Lee app

Always redirect to Appstore if the app's already installed

```
// If AddisonLee is not installed, send the user to the Apple App Store
let hereWeGoApp = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
let addisonLeeAppURL = NSURL(string: "addisonlee://")!

if hereWeGoApp.canOpenURL(addisonLeeAppURL) {
    // addisonlee is installed; launch it
    hereWeGoApp.openURL(addisonLeeAppURL)
} else {
    // addisonlee not installed; open App Store
    let addisonLeeAppStoreURL = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/addison-lee-mini-cab-taxi/id718312937?mt=8")!
    hereWeGoApp.openURL(addisonLeeAppStoreURL)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here? Perhaps you could read [ask] and then come back and edit the question to a more understandable one?

Comment: I want to redirect from my app to "Addison Lee" app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you haven't added the custom URL scheme for the Addison Lee app to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your plist.

See here for some good details on this requirement that came in with iOS9:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/

**EDIT (following comment below):**
If you don't know whether there is a custom URL scheme for an app, then you need to check the plist from inside the bundle.
Here are some good instructions on how to get hold of the bundle and open it up:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/07/extract-and-explore-an-ios-app-in-mac-os-x/

Once you've done that, you'll need to check the Info.plist file for the CFBundleURLTypes key. If it is present, then you should find the URL schemes that you're looking for.

Comment: What should I add for Addison Lee app, I want to know "Key Name". I tried addison-lee, addisonlee, AddisonLee but they are not working.Please suggest me key name.

Comment: Ok, so you've just guessed that there is a custom URL scheme for the Addison Lee app, and also guessed what that custom URL scheme is?! It's very possible that there's no way to do it then, but I'll add some instructions on how to find out...

Answer (score 0):

`addlee://` is the answer to open the app on iOS